MAUI and IFingerprint: how to authenticate the user after a resume?
In my NET8 MAUI application, I added the IFingerprint in order to authenticate the user via biometrics. It is working if the app displays a login page.
What I like to do is authenticate the user when the app is restored. For example, I added this code in the App.xaml.cs
protected override async void OnResume()
{
    base.OnResume();

    var isAvailable = await CrossFingerprint.Current.IsAvailableAsync(true);

    if (isAvailable)
    {
        var request = new AuthenticationRequestConfiguration(
            "Login using biometrics", "Confirm login with your biometrics");
        request.AllowAlternativeAuthentication = true;

        var result = await CrossFingerprint.Current.AuthenticateAsync(request);

        Console.Write(result);
    }
}

The problem I get is that the app checks the user constantly not only when the app is resumed. What is the correct implementation or best practice?

Where did you override the OnResume method? In the App.cs or the MainActivity.cs?

@LiyunZhang-MSFT In the App.cs

So what platform did you test on?

both iOS and Android

Do you mean that the project checks the user even if the OnResume method is not triggered? It is recommended to set a breakpoint for the OnResume() method to check the trigger.

Can you provide other codes of App.xaml.cs? Does your project use Shell structure?
